# I am an awful person and I hate lazers

Tags: script, javascript

### About

Don't like the hover animation on Arqade's mothership? You are probably an awful person, but here's a userscript anyway.

#### Download

**[I am an awful person and I hate lazers](http://tommedley.com/files/awful.user.js)**

#### Platform

Runs anywhere that supports userscripts; should work in all those places too.

### Code

It's all pure JavaScript. Below, for reference.

```
var css='#nav-askquestion:hover{background:url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/mothership.png") !important;}';
style=document.createElement('style');
if (style.styleSheet)
    style.styleSheet.cssText=css;
else
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```